# SAS Count how many times a value has changed over time

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that has weekly values stored by location.  I want to determine how many times the value has changed.  Initially I thought I could just count distinct values, but the issue is that sometimes the values are repeated.  Consider the example below:

```
data have;
    input location $ week value;
cards;
NC 1 100
NC 2 200
NC 3 200
NC 4 200
NC 5 100
NC 6 200
SC 1 500
SC 2 500
SC 3 500
SC 4 500
SC 5 500
SC 6 500
;
run;
```

Notice that the value at location NC changes three times, at weeks 2,5,6.  The value at location SC changes 0 times.

I would like an output of the change frequency...something like:

```
NC 3
SC 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the data is sorted.  Your example is, but if not then

```
proc sort data=have;
by location week;
run;
```

After that, use the `BY` statement inside the data step.  This will create indicators that tell you when you are at the start and end of the `BY` group.

`RETAIN`, will keep values between lines.

```
data want;
set have;
by location;

retain last count;

if first.location then do;
    count = 0;
    last = value;
end;

if last ^= value then
    count = count + 1;

last = value;

if last.location then 
    output;
run;
```

Comment: Perfect. This does exactly what I need.  I had a feeling I would be using a by group, but did not know how to implement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `NOTSORTED` keyword on a `BY` statement and you can then count the number of `FIRST.` occurrences.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by location week;
run;
data want 
  set have;
  by location value notsorted ;
  if first.location then nchange=0;
  else nchange + first.value;
  if last.location;
  keep location nchange ;
run;
```

Comment: Another excellent solution.  I use proc sql with a max function to get desired output.  Vote goes to DomPazz, but this is a good one too.

Comment: I don't think PROC SQL can handle this question because it has no way to account for the order of the rows.

Comment: I agree.  I think your initial answer had more rows than I needed, and I used proc sql group by to select the max of each group.  Looks like you accomplished the same by adding a keep statement for last.location.